# Are books only good for one use?

Tags: dont-starve

*Don't Starve* recently had an update which added [Books](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Books) for Wickerbottom, the Librarian.

These books have various effects, some of which are really pretty over-powered. Her ability to instantly grow plants and farms, and her ability to summon Tentacles, both stand out as incredibly game breaking. Given the expensive cost of books (reeds being a risky venture to acquire), I'm curious if it's a one-time use, or if you keep that book permanently.

**Are books a one-time use, permanent, or do they degrade over time?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Don't Starve wiki](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Books), different books have different durability and sanity costs:

- *Birds of the World* - **3** use, **50** sanity
- *Applied Horticulture* - **5** use, **33** sanity
- *Sleepytime Stories* - **5** use, **33** sanity
- *The End is Nigh* - **5** use, **33** sanity
- *On Tentacles* - **5** use, **50** sanity

Remember that though Wickerbottom has a much higher maximum sanity than other characters, she also have greater difficulty in gaining it due to her insomnia.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this forum](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/showthread.php?22549-Book&highlight=book), books can be used 5 times.

> Book: consumes time (two fragments of the fragments in a don't starve day).
>       Increases sanity but costs time and drains hunger. Crafted with two papyrus,
>       one manure and one crow feather. This can be used 5 times. This cannot be used
>       at night meaning that the character is probably too tired.

Comment: I don't think that actually answers the question. That appears to be from a "Suggestions" post, wherein a user suggested that books be a thing.

Comment: Yes but a later post in that thread mentions `also, Wickerbottom already has books`, which lead me to believe it is already set up like such.